# Using controllers and directives to update a view ... how do I do this?

Tags: angularjs

I've been doing angularjs for 3 days now and at the moment I'm confused with controllers and directives.

I have a situation where I need to display a value based on the options selected from a select list.  This value needs to be displayed on a part of the page that is not within the controller that displays the select list.

Is it possible to do this?  If so can anyone show me how?  Code examples would be welcome.  I'm getting nowhere fast.

From what I can tell so far the directive is tied to the controller and so what I want to do doesn't seem possible (at least using this method).

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <!-- list of credit cards -->
  <select ng-model="myOption" ng-change="selectAction()" ng-model="creditCards">
    <option ng-repeat="creditcard in creditCards" value="{{creditcard.value}}">{{creditcard.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div ng-controller="BasketCtrl">
  <!-- the card charge shown here is based on the option selected -->
  <div data-card-charge></div>
<div>
```

Comment: You could either use a parent controller that wraps both those divs and share the value there, OR use a $rootScope.$broadcast event and catch it in the other controller using $scope.$on('event', function( data, args) {} );

Comment: The two models on your select is pretty weird imo.

Comment: Cheers for the advice ...... yeah I know, there should only be one model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using `$rootScope`.

Something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/S3FjxPggoWPUGqkbs7fb?p=preview

**JS:**

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.creditCards = [
      {
      name: "Visa"
      },
      {
        name: "Mastercard"
      }
    ];

    $scope.updateValue = function (creditCard) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('cardChanged', {card: creditCard });
    };


});

app.controller('BasketCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('cardChanged', function( data, args) {
      $scope.cards = args.card;
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <!-- list of credit cards -->
  <select ng-model="myOption" ng-change="updateValue(creditCards)" ng-model="creditCards">
    <option ng-repeat="creditcard in creditCards" value="{{creditcard.value}}">{{creditcard.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div ng-controller="BasketCtrl">
  <!-- the card charge shown here is based on the option selected -->
  <div data-card-charge></div>

  <p ng-repeat="card in cards">{{ card.name }}</p>
<div>
```

Comment: This looks like it will be enough to get me going with this.  I'll check it out tomorrow and see how I get on :) ........ Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a factory to store the setting from your select. Kind of like this:

```
.factory('SelectedCreditCard', function ($timeout) {
    var _service, _data;

    _service = {};

    _data = {
        selected: undefined
    };

    _service.setSelected = function (card) {
        _data.selected = card;
    };

    _service.getSelected = function () {
        return _data;
    };

    return _service;
});
```

Then you can save selected card using SelectedCreditCard.setSelected(card) but since your using a select with ng-model we don't even need to do that, Angular takes care of the heavy lifting:

**Controller:**

```
.controller('SetController', function($scope, SelectedCreditCard) {
    $scope.creditcard = SelectedCreditCard.get();
})
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="SetController">
    <select ng-model="creditCard.selected" ng-options="card.name for card in creditCards"></select>
</div>
```

To use the selected card in you directive you could simple inject the SelectedCreditCard factory into the directive. An even cleaner way would be to send the data to the scope of BasketCtrl and the use it as an expressions for the directive:

```
<div ng-controller="BasketCtrl">
    <div data-card-charge="creditCard"></div>
<div>
```

**Also**
You have two ng-model on the select :)